# Вёрстка, разбиение на блоки

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте.

Вообщем застрял на вёрстке. Всё не могу понять, как сделать так, как на скрине. 
Что нужно написать в CSS?

Заранее спасибо.

[image]

Comment: Что именно непонятно? Как сделать таблицу в 3 строчки и вторую разбить на 3 столбца?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<table>
<tr>
<footer>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<selection1>
</td>
<td>
<selection2>
</td>
<td>
<selection3>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: а можно сделать не с помощью таблиц???

Я просто не могу понять можно ли в html5 это сделать как то

Comment: @vova666 можно с помощью тега div, но смысла в это вообще нету. Чем Вам таблица не угодила?

Comment: Так, лишь интересно стало как это можно было реализовать без таблиц. Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 5):

> а можно сделать не с помощью таблиц???
>
> Так, лишь интересно стало как это
> можно было реализовать без таблиц.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#footer
{
    background: gray;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font-family: "Verdana";
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#footer div
{
    float: left;
}
.section
{
    text-align: left;
    width: 180px;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.red
{
    background: red;
}
.green
{
    background: green;
}
.blue
{ 
    background: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="footer">
    &lt;footer&gt;
    <div class="section red">
        &lt;section&gt;
        <br />
        &bull; &lt;h1&gt;
        <br />
        &bull; &lt;ul&gt;
    </div>
    <div class="section green">
        &lt;section&gt;
        <br />
        &bull; &lt;h1&gt;
        <br />
        &bull; &lt;ul&gt;
    </div>
    <div class="section blue">
        &lt;section&gt;
        <br />
        &bull; &lt;h1&gt;
        <br />
        &bull; &lt;p&gt;
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Табличкой проще правда? Кроссбраузерность не гарантирую, но опере понравилось :)

З.Ы. почти соответственно скрину)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте таблицы только для преставления табличных данных.
Для разметки уже давно за хороший тон принято использовать блочную вёрстку.